# How to use a PID controller for different kinematics robots

Tags: pid, odometry

I implement different drive odometry for a robot. Trying to implement (proportional–integral–derivative controller) PID-based coordinate movements x, y, theta:

```
public void getX(double dt) {x += Math.cos(theta) * robotV() * dt;}
public void getY(double dt) {y += Math.sin(theta) * robotV() * dt;}
public void getTheta(double dt) {
    theta += ((rightLenV()-leftLenV()) / Constants.transmission_width)*dt;
    theta = adduction(theta);
}
public double adduction(double a){
    while (a > Math.PI) {a = a-2*Math.PI;}
    while (a < -Math.PI) {a = a+2*Math.PI;}
    return a;
}
```

my implement pid controller (bad working)

```
pidControllerVelocity = new PIDController(10, 0, 5);
public void velocity(double x_W, double y_W) {
    x_D = x_W - x;
    y_D = y_W - y;
    dS = Math.sqrt((Math.pow(x_D, 2) + Math.pow(y_D, 2)));


    u = Math.atan2(y_D, x_D);

    pidControllerVelocity.setSetpoint(adduction(u));
    double PD_velocity = pidControllerVelocity.calculate(theta);

    if (dS < 0.015) {
        leftMotor.set(0);
        rightMotor.set(0);
    } else {
        leftMotor.set(0.1+PD_velocity);
        rightMotor.set(0.1-PD_velocity);

    }
}
```

I'm working with Java library *wpilib*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The kinematics - odometry part seems okay. I think your general configuration for the controller is incorrect.

First of all, you are going to need to use two high-level controllers. One of them is going to provide the reference forward speed of your robot, V. The other one is going to provide the reference steering of the robot. Then you can map these desired values to the wheel speeds, in order to actuate your robot.

You have already calculated dS. You feed this dS to a controller (a sole P Controller may work just OK, you may not need the other terms). The output of the controller is going to be the desired speed - V_des. You also have already calculated angle "u", which is the relative angle of the vehicle to the goal point. You subtract the vehicle "theta" from this angle "u" to have the orientation error. Then, you can feed this error to a separate controller - a sole P controller may be enough for this too. The output of this controller is going to be the desired rate of orientation - Theta_dot_desired.

From your odometry function, we already know that the Theta_dot is equal to the  speed difference between the right and left wheel, divided by the wheel base. It is not written in your odometry code directly, but I believe that the robotV variable must be equal to the sum of the wheel speeds, divided by two. From these two equations, you can solve for the wheel speeds, given the desired robotV and Theta_dot.

You can use the following equations I have written as a reference:

General Kinematics, given the Wheel Speeds:

[image]

Controller Equations:

[image]

Substituting the Controller Outputs to the Kinematic Equations, in order to calculate the Inverse Kinematics:

[image]

I am not very sure about how to use your library, but I believe that you can work it out if you understand the controller structure.

Comment: the last two formulas that you wrote for vr and vl are substituted into the motors?

Comment: If the motor rotation is directly related to the wheel speeds, then yes. The last two formulas tell at what speed each wheel is required to rotate.

Comment: a rather strange bug or feature was discovered by me for some reason if I ask it to move to y= 2, then it starts to go wrong, but if y < 1 then everything is correct

Comment: There might be many different reasons to that, however, maybe since the initial positional error is too high when y = 2; a large signal is being sent to the motors. You may try add upper and lower bounds to the motor speeds.

In addition, for the orientation control you need to keep the angles between -pi, and pi. Maybe when y = 2, the result of the atan function or the overall expression produces angles which do not lie between -pi, and pi. You may consider using atan2 function, in that case.

Comment: having chosen P more correctly, the coefficient has achieved a more even ride along y, but for large y it travels in an arc to the point

Comment: I assume it is an expected thing since you are only telling your vehicle to go to a specific point only. You are not giving any trajectory for vehicle to follow. Different initial positions or different gains would yield different paths which are followed by your vehicle, given the same target point. If you want your vehicle not only go to specific point, but also follow a certain path; you can try trajectory control. The trajectory will contain many sub-points between your vehicle's position and the target point.

Comment: I implemented a system where I give two points as input when I call it, I set two points to use a set of points, I create a two-dimensional one with points. but I don't think it's right

Comment: I could not understand what you exactly mean. However, if you created  sub-system which creates a set of intermediate points (waypoints) from a desired position; then you need a trajectory control application. There are different algorithms for that, however, the one you are using right now might not be sufficient to accomplish trajectory tracking. You may want to have look at Pure-Pursuit Controller which is used on trajectory tracking applications.